# extjs 4 cannot trigger store events load and beforeload

Tags: extjs, load, store

I have an issue triggering ‘load’ and ‘beforeload’ events on stores in ext4 :

```
Ext.define('Emvr.store.saveFormData', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'Emvr.model.saveFormData',
        constructor: function(config) {
            config = config || {};
            this.callParent([config]);
        }
    });
    var store_myVisitsGrid_instance = new Emvr.store.saveFormData();


    store_myVisitsGrid_instance.on(load, function() { 
                alert('ok load'); 
    })
```

It won’t get into the function when I load the data using

```
store_myVisitsGrid_instance.loadData(responseFromServer)
```

Comment: do you see any errors? can you post them?

Comment: I am able to see in firebug that I have defined a listener for load event, but the action inside the function is not triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadData` **DOESN'T** trigger `load` event. The [`load`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method does.

Comment: Ok, this is new for ext 4, slightly different from the 3.x, where the loadData method was triggering the load event too. Now the load event, from what I'm reading from docs, "Fires whenever records have been prefetched". Do you know what prefetch method effectively does? I am loading a bunch of stores by one ajax request, and I'm using loadData to fill every store. For one specific store I will need to know when records have been loaded in order to perform some custom code. Do you know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use **datachanged** event for that purpose.

I digged in into the sources and found that the loadData method would eventually fire datachanged event. This was not happening on the old ext 3.x.